# Label of rows and columns in matrix

Tags: arrays

I want to have the label of the matrix from left to the right. Also, seems the top labels are very close to each other. (I do not want to use "blockarray" matrix). Thank you very much.

```
\begin{align}
\begin{array}{c c} &
 \begin{array}{c c } 2 \  & \ 3 \\
\end{array}
\\
 S =  \begin{array}{c c}
2\\
3
\end{array}
&
\left[
\begin{array}{c c}
S_1 & S_2  \\
S_3 & 0  
\end{array}
\right]
\end{array}
\end{align}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use `nicematrix`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{nicematrix}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
S=
\begin{bNiceMatrix}[
  first-row,code-for-first-row=\scriptstyle,
  first-col,code-for-first-col=\scriptstyle,
]
& 2 & 3 \\
2 & S_1 & S_2 \\
3 & S_3 & 0
\end{bNiceMatrix}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image]

You may require a couple of runs in order for the output to stabilize.

For the labels to the right:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{nicematrix}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
S=
\begin{bNiceArray}[
  first-row,code-for-first-row=\scriptstyle,
  last-col,code-for-last-col=\scriptstyle,
]{cc}
2   & 3   &  \\
S_1 & S_2 & 2 \\
S_3 & 0   & 3
\end{bNiceArray}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you. But I want to have the label on the right side of the matrix, not in front of "=".

Comment: @MathMath Here it is.

Comment: Thank you very much.